# How android calender setInexactRepeating works?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am developing small android application. And I want to do something in my application after some minutes. These minutes are not static one these are dynamic ones.
So i am using android calender setInexactRepeating for this.
My code looks like this

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Start something after 4 minutes 
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
        get_alaram_service().setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*300, get_pendingintent());
```

So this will work setInexactRepeating after 4 min it will run my pending intent and after that it will keep repeating this for this much amount of time. (1000*300).

So my problem is that in setInexactRepeating 2nd parameter is for at what time I want to start my timer and 3rd parameter for repeating this thing. Now 2nd parameter tales value in milisec. I tried to pass my own value of minutes in milisec like(1000*300) then its not working properly. I don't how its working properly. When I checked cal.getTimeInMillis() it is very big integer number. what is that actually.

Am i doing something wrong need your help thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't explicitly stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) the second parameter (triggerAtMillis) is time in milliseconds since the Epoch. This is what [Calendar.getInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) returns. Calling this method will return the current time. This is a big number, since it is actually the number of milliseconds after 1/1/1970. You then need to add something to it (e.g. 4 minutes) to define when the AlarmManager will first fire.